# Network Transfer Speeds (in MB/s) using Prometheus & Grafana

Tags: networking, prometheus, grafana, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to create a graph in Grafana to display the machine's network transfer speeds (in MB/s or similar) by using the following Prometheus query

```
rate(node_network_receive_bytes_total[1m]) * 8
```

However, this is giving me a very flat graph and the value seems to be in the wrong order of magnitude as well.

[image]

Prometheus is scraping the default node exporter to obtain the metrics including `node_network_receive_bytes_total` and `node_network_transmit_bytes_total`.

[image]

`iftop` is showing the download transfer speed to be about 10+ Mbps, which is much higher than 1 KBps calculated in the Grafana graph.

What should be the correct query to calculate the network transfer bandwidth in Prometheus/Grafana?

*Edit: Node exporter is running inside a Docker container.*

Answer (score 2):

It can happen if you run node exporter in docker container.
Just configure use container host system network

`docker run --network host`

or in compose add

`network_mode: host`