# Monitoring host traffic with node-exporter running in container not in local network

Tags: docker-compose, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm using docker swarm and a public network for my containers. But I need to monitor traffic usage on the machine hosting the container (whichever that is). `node_network_receive_bytes_total` seems to be the metric for that but it is measuring the container traffic, not the host's. ChatGPT recommended the following configuration, which I expected to work. It also suggested using the volume `- /var/run/netns:/var/run/netns:ro`  but there isn't a `/var/run/netns` on my machine.

I cannot use `network: local` so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606739/network-transfer-speeds-in-mb-s-using-prometheus-grafana) is not helpful. Also [this one is inconclusive](https://serverfault.com/questions/1048261/prometheus-monitor-host-network-traffic-from-within-docker-container)

```
  node_exporter:
    image: ubuntu/alertmanager:0.25.0-22.04_stable
    pid: "host"
    networks:
      - my-proxy-public
    volumes:
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /etc/hostname:/etc/nodename
    deploy:
      mode: global
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'
      - '--path.rootfs=/rootfs'
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - '--collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points=^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc)($$|/)'
      - '--collector.textfile.directory=/home/'
      - '--collector.meminfo_numa'
      - '--no-collector.ipvs'
```

How can I effectively monitor the traffic usage on the host machine instead of the container?

Comment: This is very much server/network configuration question. And you seems to be aware of [sf] existence. How come you didn't ask it there?

Comment: Also, by `network: local` do you mean `network_mode: host`? Because if yes - it's against [recommended way of monitoring host network from withing docker](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#docker).